# shell scripting default value

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I am trying to learn shell scripting and I am kind of confused with the idea of := or default value

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                             

echo "Please enter a number \c"
read input
input=$((input % 2))

if [ $input -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "The number is even"
else
    echo "The number is odd"
fi

echo "Beginning of second part"
a="BLA" 
a="Dennis"
echo $a
unset a
echo "a after unsetting"
echo $a
${a:=HI}
echo "unsetting a again"
unset a
echo $a
```

And I get this

```
Dennis
a after unsetting

./ifstatement.sh: line 21: HI: command not found
unsetting a again
```

Comment: you show less than 21 lines here, and the line shown can't give this error. Please show the whole script.

Comment: Well. this change in the edit history clears things up: 
<strike>echo</strike> ${a:=HI}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to set a value that a variable will always "fall back" to when you un-set it.  When you use the `unset` command, you are removing the variable (not just clearing the value associated with it) so it can't have *any* value, default or otherwise.

Instead, try a combination of two things.  First, make sure the variable gets initialized.  Second, create a function that sets the variable to the desired default value.  Call this variable instead of `unset`.  With this combination, you can simulate a variable having a "default" value.

Answer (score 5):

When you write

```
${a:=HI}
```

the shell splits the result of the expansion into words, and interprets the first word as a command, as it would for any command line.

Instead, write

```
: "${a:=HI}"
```

`:` is a no-op command. The quotes prevent the shell from trying to do globbing, which in rare circumstances could cause a slowdown or an error.

Answer (score 0):

`${a:=HI}` expands to `HI`, which your shell then tries to run as a command.  If you're just trying to set the value of a variable if it is not set, you may want to do something like `[ -z "$b" ] && b=BYE`

Comment: i actually want to set a default value in a variable so that if i unset it the default variable will show up

Comment: Hmm, that's not what := does.  := just expands to the value on the right if the left is not defined.  It would be like `"#{a || 'HI'}"` in ruby

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `unset $a`, you do `${a:=HI}` again

Comment: isnt that the purpose of setting a default value though? once you unset a variable and you echo it, the default value should show up.

Comment: That's because when you unset, you are removing the variable.